# Git always tells me the personal file add to Xcode. I have added the ignore of Objective-C

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

This is the  git status:

On branch long_10009gitignore
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

> modified:   Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/myName.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
>       modified:   myCompany.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/myName.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I have added the .ignore of Objective-C. Why git calls me to add the files above.
 Who know how should I do?

`.gitignore`'s content:

```
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata

## Other
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
*.xcuserstate
*.xcscmblueprint

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
#
# Pods/

# Carthage
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage dependencies.
# Carthage/Checkouts

Carthage/Build

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the 
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/docs/Gitignore.md

fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/screenshots
```

Comment: show me `.gitignore` and `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subdirectories and files, you have to need `/*` at the end.

```
## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap/*
*.ipa/*
```

After editing, type `git ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard` to lists all ignored files in this project.

You can confirm what is ignored with that command, and if you want to undo the commits, type
`git reset [commit]`

Comment: I want to ignore the file named ".xcuserstate".

Comment: @jiexishede did you try `.xcuserstate` ?